# Error setting certificate while doing 'git clone' in redhat

Tags: rhel, git, github

Error:

```
% git clone --depth 1 http://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/Downloads/fzf
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/Downloads/fzf/.git/
error: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none while accessing http://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git/info/refs
```

rhel Version:

```
% cat  /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

ca-certificates does not seem to be installed:

```
% which ca-certificates
/usr/bin/which: no ca-certificates in ( ... )
```

I do not have root privileges so is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the certificates where git expects them. The same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository).